# L’Hopital’s rule for (infinity over minus infinity)

Tags: limits

Can I apply L’Hopital’s rule to this:

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} 
$$

when $
\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = \infty
$ and $
\lim_{x\to0}g(x) = -\infty
$. Is this an indeterminate form?

Comment: Get rid of $n$ please

Comment: Yes, l’Hospital’s rule applies in this case.

Comment: L'Hopital aplies whenever $g(x) \to \pm \infty,$ no matter what $f$ is doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ in which $\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = \infty,$ and $\lim_{x\to0}g(x) = -\infty$ (or vice versa)

or informally,  $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac {f(x)}{g(x)} \to  \dfrac \infty{-\infty} $, and/or such a limit that approaches $\frac {-\infty}\infty$

are indeterminate forms.

A handy list of the other indeterminate forms is given by [Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms). The entry itself is rather useful.

You can use  l’Hospital’s rule in such each case above.

Comment: This form isn't on that list. Has something changed?